# How to add horizontal scroll with pinned columns AG Grid - Angular

Tags: angular, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have multiple columns groups in my Ag-Grid Column Definitions and in them first one static pinned columns and remaining groups will be calculated based on given date, and I want to pinned first column group to left but the thing is it contain 10 number of columns and on pinning left they occupy all of view port, so I hoping someone guide me how to add horizontal scroll on pinned columns or to set max-width of column group to show horizontal scroll.

Here are my Column Definitions:

```
export const approvalGridColDefs = (startDate) => {
  const approvalGridColDefs = [];
  approvalGridColDefs.push({
    headerName: '',
    children: [
      {
        headerName: 'Internal SKU ID',
        field: 'internalSKUId',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Status',
        field: 'actionName',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Item Description',
        field: 'itemDescription',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Release Date',
        field: 'releaseDate',
        type: 'date',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Account',
        field: 'accountName',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Fixture',
        field: 'fixture',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'UPC',
        field: 'upc',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Class Name',
        field: 'className',
        // hide: true,
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Rating',
        field: 'ratingName',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Theatrical Release',
        field: 'theatricalReleaseDate',
        type: 'date',
        pinned: 'left',
        suppressToolPanel: true
      }
    ]
  });
  for (let weekIndex = 1; weekIndex <= 8; weekIndex++) {
    const weekDate = addWeeks(new Date(startDate), weekIndex);
    approvalGridColDefs.push({
      headerName: moment(weekDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
      field: `week${weekIndex}`,
      marryChildren: true,
      headerClass: 'approval-column-group',
      cellStyle: { textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' },
      children: [
        {
          headerName: 'Promo Price',
          field: `promoPriceWeek${weekIndex}`,
          editable: true,
          cellEditor: 'numericCellEditor',
          headerClass: 'approval-first-header',
          cellStyle: { borderLeft: '2px solid lightgray' }
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Margin Credit',
          field: `marginCreditWeek${weekIndex}`,
          editable: true,
          cellEditor: 'numericCellEditor'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'B&M Promo Week Forecast',
          field: `bAndMPromoForecastWeek${weekIndex}`,
          editable: true,
          cellEditor: 'numericCellEditor'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Dotcom Week Forecast',
          field: `dotComForecastWeek${weekIndex}`,
          editable: true,
          cellEditor: 'numericCellEditor'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'On Ad',
          field: `onAdWeek${weekIndex}`,
          editable: true,
          cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
          cellEditorParams: {
            values: extractValues(yesNoMapping)
          },
          filterParams: {
            valueFormatter: function (params) {
              return lookupValue(yesNoMapping, params.value);
            },
          },
          valueFormatter: params => {
            return lookupValue(yesNoMapping, params.value);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }
  return approvalGridColDefs;
}
```

By default no horizontal scroll is visible because pinned columns occupy all of the space and after adjusting the width of individual column here is how the grid is showing:
[image]

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: @Upendra I haven't found it yet

Comment: @NazirAhmed any luck with how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a requirement like this. What I suggest is that you make the pinned column a separate grid.
You can then align the two grids there is a section in ag grid which will then act as one grid.[ag grid aligned grids](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/aligned-grids/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Downvoted because the grid alignment feature you linked shows two columns stacked one on top of the other and the columns are aligned. For your suggestion to work, the grids must be shown side by side instead of stacked and the grid must align the rows, not the columns. Such a feature, as far as I can see, does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

We had this requirement for many of our Grids at work.

We fixed it by setting a value for pinnedWidth in our AdapTable Layout.  This then created the horizontal scrollbar automatically if the pinned columns width was greater than that width.

See https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/dev-guide-tutorial-tips-and-tricks#scrollbar-in-pinned-columns

Comment: What if we're not using AdapTable? This question is about AG-Grid not AdapTable.